# Click listener not triggering when previous sibling has z-index

Tags: javascript, css, event-listener

I have a table which consists of a sticky first column and then a number of additional columns which contain `input` fields. Each field has a sort of floating toolbar that should appear when the input element has focus. It looks roughly like this:

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
}
```

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

input:focus+.toolbar {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky">Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>
      <input>
      <div class="toolbar"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input>
      <div class="toolbar"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input>
      <div class="toolbar"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(I'm not 100% sure if I inserted it right into this snippets feature, if it doesn't work, just save it to a local file and run it there)

As you can see, the showing/hiding of the floating toolbar element works as expected. It is shown for all columns at the expected position when the field has focus. Now here is the thing I don't understand: The toolbar's click listener works for all columns, except for the first one (i.e. the one next to the sticky column). When I click that one, the toolbar just disappears (because the input lost focus), but the click listener is not run.

The problem disappears when I remove the `z-index` from the first column, but I can't, because it needs to be there for sticky to work properly. Also, if this was only a z-index problem, shouldn't the toolbar be below the sticky `td`?

It almost seems that what happens is:

- click on the toolbar triggers loss of focus on `input`
- loss of focus on `input` causes `.toolbar` to go below `.sticky`
- the browser now decides for some reason that the element you clicked was not actually clickable and doesn't run the event handler

I have reproduced this in FF and Chrome, but I don't understand if it is some kind of a browser bug or is it me not understanding the event model well enough. Does anyone have some insights or links to relevant documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add z-index: 2 to .toolbar and it will be fixed.

At the moment the other clicks work because the other columns have no z-index. When you added z-index: 1 to the column the result was that the column was shown over the toolbar. Now, since you cannot remove that z-index what makes sense is to give an increased z-index to what you would like to be shown on top of the column, in this case the toolbar.

Comment: Hm, that works in the reduced sample above, but not in my real code. There seems to be something else causing it then...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add `pointer-events: none` to the sticky element and that should the job.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work in my real code, because the sticky element contains links

Comment: So, you can just add _z-index: 2_ to the toolbar. I guess that will work just fine